# Autopsy on netbeans giving java version error

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to run autopsy on windows, netbeans.
I am getting unsupported java version 13 
Make sure that the java version is 1.8.0_66 or higher

https://github.com/sleuthkit/autopsy

I set up enviroment variables, and its not working.

When I echo %JAVA_HOME%

I am getting C:\Programfiles/java/jre1.8.0_241

java -version prints 1.8.0_241

I also went to check netbeans.conf

found the property named “netbeans_jdkhome”. it is set correctly to
Windows Systems, this might be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2).

Build.xml

```
<condition property="supported-java-versions">
        <or>​
            <matches string="${java.version}" pattern="1\.8\.0_6[6-9]"/>​
            <matches string="${java.version}" pattern="1\.8\.0_[7-9][0-9]"/>​
            <matches string="${java.version}" pattern="1\.8\.0_[1-9][0-9][0-9]"/>​
            <matches string="${java.version}" pattern="1\.8\.[1-9]_[0-9][0-9]"/>​
            <equals arg1="${ant.java.version}" arg2="1.9"/>​
        </or>​
    </condition>
```

Comment: What does `java -version` print?

Comment: In cmd window, if you run `java --version` what do you get?

Comment: @Rafael - it is `-version`.  (The manual says ...)

Comment: @StephenC `--version` and `-version` both are correct keys

Comment: I edited my  post, it is prinitng 1.8.0_241. Also checked netbeans.conf for netbeans_jdkhome

Comment: @Rafael I don't know for Java 11, but for java 6 to 8, there is only one dash

Comment: so any help? I see everything i set was correct. Why is it not working?

Comment: I added build.xml for you as well, where its detecting I need java 1.8.0_66 or higher

Comment: @user3278732 looks like you have 2 java installations. 1 - Java Virtual Machine (version 8), that has been added to the PATH and you get the correct version upon calling `java -version`. And the second - JDK (version 13). Is this true?

Comment: yeh,... I have C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.2 and i have C:\Programfiles/java/jre1.8.0_241

Answer (score 0):

[This is not necessarily a solution to your problem, but is too long to post as a comment.]

You haven't specified your NetBeans version, but for all versions note that:

- NetBeans doesn't care at all about the settings of environment variables such as **JAVA_HOME**. They are completely irrelevant. Checking the value of `java -version` from the command line is also irrelevant; it proves/disproves nothing.
- NetBeans does care about the value of **netbeans_jdkhome** in **netbeans.conf**, and it will use it (if set).

In your case it seems that **netbeans_jdkhome** has a value that specifies the path to your JDK 13 installation. If you are running NetBeans 8.2 that is an invalid path since 8.2 does not support Java versions > 1.8. The fix is to edit **netbeans.conf** and set **netbeans_jdkhome** to specify the path to your Java 8 installation.

If you are not running NetBeans 8.x please update your question with details of your NetBeans installation. You can get that by copying and pasting the output from the **Help > About** window.